# Radiant Rig XL does not work with my character mesh because there is a script that interferes with it

Tags: rigging, add-on, rigify

I'm trying to make work the add-on called "Radiant Rig XL" with the character that I usually use to learn blender. I don't why,but it does not work,like you can see from this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNaueGprbkExbTJvaFk/view).

and you can find the character that I'm working with [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauZk5TYTV3dXN0dDg/view?usp=sharing).

I sent an email to the author of the script and he replied to me telling :

> "You have a script attached which interferes with Rigify (rig_ui.py). Radiant Rig depends upon Rigify as stated in the instructions.
>   If you are changing Rigify, I can't predict what will happen"

I disabled the option called "auto run python scripts" from the user preferences panel because I wanted to disable the "rig_ui.py" script,but it didn't work. Can someone of you be more specific ? How can I disable the interfering script ? What is this ? I don't know anything about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here were the steps I took to diagnose the problem you are having:

1) When I opened your file, I saw the error message "Auto-run disabled: Text 'rig_ui.py'" (see screen shot 1)
[image: Screen Shot 1]

2) Near the Help item at the top, I switched the layout from 'gp2' to 'Scripting' (see screen shot 2)
[image: Screen Shot 2]

3) I saw a script which is designed to modify the rigify plugin. Radiant Rig depends upon Rigify as stated in the instructions. If you are changing Rigify, I can't predict what will happen. I did not have time in the morning to debug the rig_ui.py attached to your file. (see screen shot 3)

[image: Screen Shot 3]

4) I selected the figure in your file and merged all the parts into one object (CTRL+J)

5) I exported your object.

6) I created a blank blender file; I was able to import the exported figure into this new file.

7) I ran my script and it fitted the mesh better.

Please follow those exact steps.

Comment: 4colorgrapix said : "I've found an error with Blender 2.79. That was why I could not replicate your error. Try the version 4.1 of the addon".

Comment: Please quote what I actually wrote:

> I've found an error with Blender 2.79. That was why I could not
> replicate your error. I've updated my code for that version. You'll
> get an official email through Gumroad with the update.

It gives other readers a false impression of what I communicated. I don't appreciate having my words changed in a public discussion.

Comment: but man,I haven't changed your words fraudulently,I made a summary.

Comment: I apologize for my reaction.